# Partial Image upload?

Tags: javascript, image, image-uploading, partial

I am creating a user flow that allows users to edit an svg and save continuously via javascript. However, I don't like saving the image file over and over again.  Is there a way to do a partial upload?  I know you can do a GET with the image, color, and coordinates.  Is there a way to similarly do POST?  I.e. only send the server the change that occurred to update the image file with?

Comment: You want to upload only changed (added, modified or deleted) elements of SVG?

Comment: Yes.  But really, its just modification.

Comment: I think it's a lot of work for little optimisation.

Comment: Its an autosave feature, so I would be looking at uploading ~100kb every few minutes for an estimate of 2 saves per minute.  Trying to get the flow changed and the autosave feature tossed, but I'm doing my investigations in the meantime

Comment: If you simply want to avoid user lose his work, you can save locally (with localStorage) and upload less often

Comment: We are considering this option as well

Comment: SVG is text. Find a JS library that can do diff between 2 text documents, send the diff to the server and merge on the server side. I'm sure you'll find a JS implementation that does both diff and merging the diffs.